# How do I use the IFileDialogCustomize::GetEditBoxText() method?

Tags: visual-c++

```
WCHAR wcText[100] = {0};
WCHAR *pText = wcText;
WCHAR **ppText = &pText;

HRESULT hr = pDialogCustomize->GetEditBoxText(dwCtrlID, ppText);
```

The edit box contains the text "5000" but this text isn't returned by the `GetEditBoxText` method.

How can I get the text from the edit box?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775908%28VS.85%29.aspx, GetEditBoxText allocates and returns a string for you (that you must later free with CoTaskMemFree). I'm assuming that you're checking the wcText array after the function call, and it is empty? This is because GetEditBoxText is changing the value of pText.

Try:

```
WCHAR *pText = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pDialogCustomize->GetEditBoxText(dwCtrlID, &pText);

if (S_OK == hr && NULL != pText)
  // function succeeded and pText points to a buffer of text that must free when done using
```

Comment: I'm still not getting any results.  Since I'm putting '5000' into the edit box I'm expecting to get '5000' returned.  Here is some additional code: const DWORD SPECTRAPERFILE = 5;   AddEditBox(SPECTRAPERFILE, "5000");   WCHAR *pText = NULL;
 HRESULT hr = pDialogCustomize->GetEditBoxText(SPECTRAPERFILE, &pText);

 if (hr == S_OK && pText != NULL) 
 {
  // Success
  CString sResult = *pText;

}

Comment: I found that I can only get the text from the Edit box when the dialog is still displayed.  After the dialog is dismissed the text is not returned.  The state of a checkbox seems to be reliably returned, even after the dialog is dismissed.  The IShellItem looks like it only provides the display name.  How can I save the text from the edit box?

Comment: Here is some code that demonstrates the problem.  The dialog must still be open for any text to be returned but the state of the checkbox is returned even if the dialog is not still open. hr = pDialog->Show(nullptr);

 // Get the text from the edit box - Dialog must be present
 WCHAR *pText = NULL;
 hr = pDialogCustomize->GetEditBoxText(1000, &pText);
 CString sText(pText);

 // Get the state of the check box - Dialog doesn't need to be present
 BOOL bChecked(FALSE);
 BOOL *pbChecked = &bChecked;
 hr = pDialogCustomize->GetCheckButtonState(1001, pbChecked);

Comment: Apparently I need to implement a callback object through the IFileDialog::Advise() method.  I haven't been able to find much in the way of sample code or details about how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you'll need to implement a new class that inherits from IFileDialogEvents (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775876%28VS.85%29.aspx) - I don't know whether you need to implement all of the them or just the ones you wish to override. I recommend starting with just the one(s) you care about and then, if needed, the others to make it happy if it complains. Something like: `class MyFileDialogValidator : public IFileDialogEvents { HRESULT OnFileOk(IFileDialog* dlg) { /* stuff */ }; }`.  IFileDialogEvents is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775876%28VS.85%29.aspx